# Pandas frame.append method is deprecated - how to update syntax?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following snippet of code, which results in warnings after updating to `pandas==1.4.3`:

```
        df_phys = pd.DataFrame()
        for db in self.db_list:
            df_decoder = can_decoder.DataFrameDecoder(db)

            df_phys_temp = pd.DataFrame()
            for length, group in df_raw.groupby("DataLength"):
                df_phys_group = df_decoder.decode_frame(group)
                df_phys_temp = df_phys_temp.append(df_phys_group)

            df_phys = df_phys.append(df_phys_temp.sort_index())
```

Can you clarify how I can transition to using `concat` within a loop as above?

Comment: "how I can transition to using concat within a loop" - don't use it inside the loop. Use it once, after the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach would be to make a list of dataframes and then concat them all in one step after the for loop. Here a runable example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_list = []
for _ in range(5):
    df_list.append(pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(2, 2)), columns=['A', 'B']))

df = pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index=True)
```

In your example you would do this once for the outer and once for the inner for loop.

As described in the [pandas Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html), this improves performance in comparison to doing lots of appends (or lots of concats).

Answer (score 0):

In principle, the following code snippet should work to fix the warning:

```py
        df_phys = pd.DataFrame()
        for db in self.db_list:
            df_decoder = can_decoder.DataFrameDecoder(db)

            df_phys_temp = pd.DataFrame()
            for length, group in df_raw.groupby("DataLength"):
                df_phys_group = df_decoder.decode_frame(group)
                df_phys_temp = pd.concat([df_phys_temp, df_phys_group], ignore_index=True)

            df_phys = pd.concat([df_phys, df_phys_temp.sort_index()], ignore_index=True)
```